# How to get a warning on "shiny app will not work if the same output is used twice"

Tags: r, shiny

This is an old Shiny issue:  [shiny app will not work if the same "output" is used two times in Ui.R](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/743)

A simple example :

```
library(shiny)
## app.R ##
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")
              # If the next line is commented out, histogram appears correctly
              ,plotOutput("distPlot")
              )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This doesn't work because :

> Shiny doesn't support multiple outputs with the same name. This code would generate HTML where two elements have the same ID, which is invalid HTML. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45162774/13513328) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458784/13513328).

The result looks fine, but isn't what is expected (no histogram shown) :
[image]

The ShinyApp seems to be working normally :

```
Listening on http ://127.0.0.1:7081
```

Although I know this issue, I have already been tricked a few times in complex UIs, and I was wondering if there was a way to output an automatic warning in the console on this?
For example :

```
Warning message: Output 'distPlot' is used twice in UI - this is not supported and might lead to unexpected results
```

Thanks for sharing your solutions on this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it may be quite some task to print it out to the R console. But if you open your app and go to the JS console you should see an error message:

[image: Duplicate]

---

Feedback as requested (here in the answer to allow for formatting purposes):

Your code covers basic cases, but there are some edge cases which you may be overlooking (this list does not claim to be exhaustive):

1. If the name of the output element is in the next line, your code will not detect it.
2. If the name of the element is not a string but in a variable it won't work either.

(and this are just 2 cases I can quickly think of - and they are not completely unrealistic to be honest)

Overall, I think it will be quite some work to cover *all* cases, while a quick look into the JS console reveals all you need, just in a different environment. IMHO completeness beats convenience.

```r
outname <- "distPlot"
ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"),
                plotOutput(
                   "distPlot" # not covered b/c in other line
                ),
                plotOutput(outname) # not covered b/c in variable
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't think about this but it really makes sense. I'll wait a while to accept it because a warning in the console would still be more visible.

Comment: I was toying with the idea to create an error handler on the JavaScript side and informing  R via `Shiny.setInputValue`, however this approach would not work because apparently the error in [Shiny javascript](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/e7ec5e5ba4915a4bf57ac8f21166ea916b44e379/srcjs/shinyapp.js#L339) prevents the `Shiny` javascript objetc to be properly instantiated, so we cnanot go through this route.

Comment: interested in feedback on the answer I posted

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that most Shiny UI outputs follow this pattern :

```
outputTypeOutput("outputname")
```

I wrote the `checkShinyOutput` function which can be called before UI definition in UI script :

```
checkShinyOutput <- function(){
  tryCatch({
      parsed <- getParseData(parse(file = rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
      shinyOutput <- parsed[parsed$token=='SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL'& grepl("^[a-z]+[A-z]+Output$",parsed$text),]
      shinyOutput <- merge(shinyOutput,parsed,by='line1')
      shinyOutput <- shinyOutput[shinyOutput$token.y == "STR_CONST",]
      warn <- table(shinyOutput$text.y)
      warn <- warn[warn>=2]
      warnname <- names(warn)
      if (length(warn>1)) {
       warning(mapply(function(warn,nb){paste("Output",warn,"is used",nb,"times")},warnname,warn))
      }
    },
    error = function(){},
    warning = function(cond) {
      message("Shiny UI : check following warnings to avoid unexpected UI behaviour")
      message(cond)
    } 
  )
}
```

This appears in Console when the app is run from RStudio :

```
> runApp('test')
Shiny UI : check following warnings to avoid unexpected UI behaviour
Output "distPlot" is used 2 times
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7414
```

Comment: Feedback in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was aware that it would only cover basic cases, but this is up to now 100% of my shiny use ;-). But agree with you, when there's a problem, just have a look at the js console.