# Reset actionButton to display modaldialog more than once in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a dashboard that I need to have a help button on to display some information if a user needs some extra information. I want to be able to hit the help button as many times as needed. Right now I am using the same actionButton for the help across multiple tabs, but the modalDialog will only show up after the first time clicking on the button. How can I reset the actionButton so I can display the modalDialog as many times as needed?

Executable code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)

tabset1 = tabsetPanel(id = "mtcars",
                            tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",
                                     fluidRow(actionButton("helpme", "?????"), box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                            )),
                            
                            
                            tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",
                                     fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
                            ))



tabset2 = tabsetPanel(id = "iris",
                      tabPanel(id = "iris","iris plots",
                               fluidRow(actionButton("helpme", "?????"), box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                               )),
                      
                      
                      tabPanel(id = "mttable","iris tables",
                               fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
                      ))

ui <- dashboardPage(

  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
    selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
    sliderInput("mtlines", "Number of lines", 1,50,10),
    

menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),    
    selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris)),
    sliderInput("irislines", "Number of lines", 1,50,10)
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("ir", tabset2),
      tabItem("mt", tabset1)
      )
      
    )
  )






# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$helpme, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "What is the meaning of life?",
      "THE MEANING OF LIFE IS 42",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
  
  

  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + geom_histogram()
    
    
  })
  
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + geom_histogram()
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    head(mtcars, input$mtlines)
    
  })
 
  
  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    head(iris, input$irislines)
    
  })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shiny [doesn't allow to use twice the same output in two different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62635457/13513328), and there's no warning for it.
This is what happened here because output `helpme` is used in two tabs.
A work around is to create two different `helpme`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)

tabset1 = tabsetPanel(id = "mtcars",
                      tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",
                               fluidRow(actionButton("helpme1", "?????"), box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                               )),
                      
                      
                      tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",
                               fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
                      ))



tabset2 = tabsetPanel(id = "iris",
                      tabPanel(id = "iris","iris plots",
                               fluidRow(actionButton("helpme2", "?????"), box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                               )),
                      
                      
                      tabPanel(id = "mttable","iris tables",
                               fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
                      ))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
      selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
      sliderInput("mtlines", "Number of lines", 1,50,10),
      
      
      menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),    
      selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris)),
      sliderInput("irislines", "Number of lines", 1,50,10)
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("ir", tabset2),
      tabItem("mt", tabset1)
    )
    
  )
)






# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$helpme1, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "What is the meaning of life?",
      "THE MEANING OF LIFE IS 42",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
  observeEvent(input$helpme2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "What is the meaning of life?",
      "THE MEANING OF LIFE IS 42",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
  
  
  
  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + geom_histogram()
    
    
  })
  
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + geom_histogram()
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    head(mtcars, input$mtlines)
    
  })
  
  
  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    head(iris, input$irislines)
    
  })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You could also use only one `output$helpme` in the header.