# How to change sidebarPanel for every tabPanel in the Main Panel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to develop an app with a layout similar to Radiant in the Shiny gallery (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/radiant.html).  In that app, the sidebarPanel changes for each tabPanel that exists in the mainPanel.  How is that accomplished?  This picture shows my layout, where I want the sidebarPanel (empty now) to change based on which tab (Metadata, Raw Data, QC Data) is chosen by the user.  Does someone either know how to do this or can you point me to where the ui code in the Radiant app is located?

[image]

EDIT: After receiving the answer below, I edited the code to look like this, rather than put the sidebar in a new function.  It is not working yet, however.  Shouldn't it?  What's still wrong?

```
    ui <- navbarPage(title = "SD Mesonet Quality Control", id = "navbarPage",
                     tabPanel(title = 'Data',
                              sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                  conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected == 1",
                                                   actionButton('bt','button Tab 1')
                                  ),
                                  conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected == 2",
                                                   selectInput('select','choice',choices=c("A","B"))
                                  )
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "tabselected",
                                              tabPanel("Instrumentation", value = 1, plotOutput("plot")),
                                              tabPanel("Metadata", value = 2, plotOutput("plot"))
                                  )
                                )
                              ),
                     )
    )
    
    
    server <- function(input,output){
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a conditional panel, see [this use case](https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/c593799bc7d8557dc863411bb552e4f4) or this [demo](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/conditionalpanel-demo.html).
To answer your question, you can link the condition of the panel to the id of the tab :

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1",
                     actionButton('bt','button Tab 1')
                     ),

    conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                     selectInput('select','choice',choices=c("A","B"))
                     )
    )
)

# Header ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Test conditional panel")

# Body ----
body <- dashboardBody(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("tab1", value=1,
                h4("Tab 1 content")),
      tabPanel("tab2", value=2,
               h4("Tab 2 content")),
      id = "tabselected"
    )
  )
)
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Tab 1 selected :
[image]
Tab 2 selected :
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  I edited my question to include my new code, which is not working.  I'm trying to embed the conditionalPanels in the normal code, rather than write functions for it.  Maybe it's because I'm trying to use navbarPage rather than shinyDashboard or something - I don't know.  Do I have to use functions like your code to get this to work?

Comment: Your code should work but doesn't because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62635457/13513328). Don't hesitate to upvote : the more people know, the better! You used twice plotOutput('plot')... just rename one of the outputs to `plot2` and try again ;)